# Image Fields In ModelForms in Django

Tags: python, django, forms, django-models, django-forms

I want to create a modelform that follows the model below but I do not know how to create an foreign key and imagefield in modelforms
please help me thanks
[this is my model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcRtB.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, as I understand, you need to create a model **Image** with ForeignKey to Post.

create this model:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, ...)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=...)
```

create this form:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    image = forms.ImageField()
    
    class Meta:
        model = Post
```

and know in your html add that field. for example:

```
<form ...>{% csrf_token %}
   ...
   {{ form.image }}
</form>
```

then in your view:

```
post = form.save()
images = self.request.FILES.getlist('image')
for img in images:
   Image.objects.create(post=post, image=img) # or with bulk create
```